# Style of error bar in pandas plot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, plot

I'd like to plot line chart with error bar with the following style.

[image]

However, pandas plot draws error bars with only vertical line.

```
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(yerr=[0.3,.3,.3])
```

[image]

How do I change style of error bar for pandas plot?

The versions are:

- pandas '0.18.0'
- matplotlib '1.5.1'

### Update

One of the reason seems using the seaborn style. The following code give the nice style plot.

```
# plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(yerr=[0.3,.3,.3],capsize=4)
```

But, I have a reason to keep using seaborn style... Please help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can change the capsize inline when you call `plot` on your `DataFrame`, using the `capsize` kwarg (which gets passed on to [`plt.errorbar`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.errorbar)):

```
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(yerr=[0.3,.3,.3],capsize=4)
```

---

Alternatively, you can change this setting using [`rcParams`](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#dynamic-rc-settings)

You can find out what your default errorbar cap size is by printing `plt.rcParams['errorbar.capsize']`. If that is 0 (which is why I suspect you are currently getting no errorbar caps), you can set the default size of the errorbar caps to something nonzero, using:

```
plt.rcParams['errorbar.capsize']=4
```

Make sure to have that at the beginning of any plotting script.

---

#### Update:

It seems using the `seaborn-paper` style sets the cap thickness to 0. You can override this with the `capthick` kwarg:

```
plt.style.use('seaborn-paper')
pd.DataFrame([1,2,3]).plot(yerr=[0.3,.3,.3],capsize=4,capthick=1)
```